# Mantener la dirección actual al enviar un email mediante un formulario usando recaptcha de Google

Tags: php, ajax

Parte del código de mi web es el siguiente formulario para enviar un `email`. Se validan los campos usando `bootstrapValidator`. Todo funciona correctamente, pero al enviar el email el navegador se redirecciona a `ajaxSubmit.php`y la intención es que se quede donde esta. Que **no se redireccione**.

Como se aprecia en el código utilizo `recaptcha` de Google. Si  usar el recaptcha de google y eliminando `data-callback="onSubmit"`del boton de envio, todo funciona correctamente

Parte de `index.php`

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {

 document.getElementById("soporteForm").submit();

}
</script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="soporteForm" method="post" action="ajaxSubmit.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control campos" placeholder="Izena" name="nombre" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="email" class="form-control campos" placeholder="Posta elektronikoa" name="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <textarea class="form-control campos" placeholder="Mezua" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button type=submit class="btn btn-default g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My_SECRET_KEY" data-callback="onSubmit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="correcto">
    Mensaje enviado correctamente
  </div>

</form>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

El el fichero `main.js`se realizan las comprobaciones de los campos y se coloca como visible la etiqueta `correcto`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var nav = $('.navbar-fixed-top');

    var distancia = $('.navbar-fixed-top').offset();

    if(distancia.top > 0){
        nav.removeClass('normal').addClass('efecto');
    }


    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >=300){
            nav.removeClass('normal').addClass('efecto');
        }else{
            nav.removeClass('efecto').addClass('normal');
        }
    })

    $('section#pantallas a').on('click',function(){
        $('#modal img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-image-url'));
    })

    $('section#app .anima1').waypoint(function(){
        $('section#app .anima1').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#app .anima2').waypoint(function(){
        $('section#app .anima2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#app .anima3').waypoint(function(){
        $('section#app .anima3').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#caracteristicas #appCentral').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInDownBig');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#caracteristicas .anima1').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#caracteristicas .anima2').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#pantallas .anima1').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#pantallas .anima2').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#pantallas .anima3').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#descargar .anima1').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#descargar .anima2').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('section#descargar .anima3').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    },{
        offset:'60%'
    });

    $('#soporteForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message:"Esto no es válido",
        feedbackIcons:{
            valid:'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid:'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating:'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields:{
            nombre:{
                validators:{
                    notEmpty:{
                        message: "Atal hau betebeharrekoa da"

                    },
                }

            },
            email:{
                validators:{
                    notEmpty:{
                        message: "Atal hau betebeharrekoa da"

                    },
                    emailAddress:{
                        message: "Honek ez dirudi posta elektroniko bat"

                    }
                }

            },
            mensaje:{
                validators:{
                    notEmpty:{
                        message: "Mezua ezin du hutsik egon"
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target);

        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result){
            $('#correcto').fadeIn();
            console.log(result);
        }, 'json');
    });

});

smoothScroll.init({
    selector: '[data-scroll]', // Selector for links (must be a valid CSS selector)
    selectorHeader: '[data-scroll-header]', // Selector for fixed headers (must be a valid CSS selector)
    speed: 700, // Integer. How fast to complete the scroll in milliseconds
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad', // Easing pattern to use
    offset: 0, // Integer. How far to offset the scrolling anchor location in pixels
    updateURL: false, // Boolean. If true, update the URL hash on scroll
    callback: function ( anchor, toggle ) {} // Function to run after scrolling
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un `<iframe id="request">` y direccionar la acción del formulario a dicho **iframe** con `target="request"`. ten en cuenta que **ajaxSubmit.php** se ejecutara en el **iframe** y este es quien debe hacer visible la etiqueta **id="correcto"**

Otro error que veo en tu código es que envías el formulario como normalmente se hace con: `action="..."` pero sin embargo veo que en los **script** que utilizas **ajax** para enviarlo tambien?. te recomiendo que coloques en tu rutina `onSubmit() {return false;}`

Ejemplo:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {

return false;
// document.getElementById("soporteForm").submit();

}
</script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="soporteForm" method="post" 
action="ajaxSubmit.php" target="request">
...
...
...
  <iframe name="request" style="display:none">
  </iframe>

  <div id="correcto">
    Mensaje enviado correctamente
  </div>

</form>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

El siguiente ejemplo muestra de manera simple como validar el formulario con ***html5*** y enviarlo con ***Ajax***.

Ejemplo:

```js
function sendForm() {

 // Prevenir el Evento submit():
 event.preventDefault();

 // aqui colocas tu codigo ajax
 // donde envias el formulario
 console.log("Send in Progress...");

 var $form = $(event.target);

 $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
  $('#postSuccessful').fadeIn();
 }, 'json');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ajaxSubmit.php" onsubmit="sendForm()">
 codigo del cliente<br><input required><br>
 Nombre del cliente<br><input required><br>
 Direccion<br><input required><br>
 Telefono<br><input required><br>
 Email<br><input required><br>

 <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="postSuccessful" style="display:none">Formulario Recibido, Gracias!</div>
```

Espero esto te ayude... Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: Me esta abriendo `ajaxSubmit.php` en otra pestaña

Comment: Disculpa hubo un error, lo correcto es: `<iframe name="request"`, ya hago la corrección.

Comment: De este modo no se redirecciona pero los campos pueden ser vacíos. Es como que no se llama en ningún momento a `main.js`

Comment: Creo que tienes otros problemas a parte del que mencionas en tu pregunta

Comment: Efectivamente, apenas uso jquery y javascript y en ocasiones me cuesta entender el funcionamiento

Comment: Cualquier duda que tengas en el uso de dichas herramientas sabes que puedes aclararlas aqui en esSO, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: ya entiendo cual es el problema en tu código, modificare mi pregunta con la solución.

Comment: Al coloclar `onSubmit() {return false;}` tal vez el problema este en código del botón?

Comment: el problema esta que si quitas la funcionalidad `<input type="submit"...` el formulario no se validara como esperas, es por ello que debes mantenerlo pero colocar `return false;` para que no se envíe el formulario por las vías normales.

Comment: Sí. Eso lo he entendido. Lo curioso es que haciendo eso no se envía el formulario.

Comment: @aldakur te acabo de dejar un ejemplo sencillo de como validar el formulario con html5 y enviarlo con ajax sin que esto refresque la pagina, Saludos!! ;)...

Comment: Muchas gracias. No es justo lo que tenía en mente, pero es prácticamente lo mismo y la pregunta queda completamente resuelta. gran trabajo!

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando AJAX POST de Jquery evitas la redirección

```
$(function() {
//Validcion
    $(#soporteForm).submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxSubmit.php',
            data: {
                   nombre:$(this).nombre.value,
                   //resto de los campos
                  }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
})
```